# Calculating the mean in an urn problem

Tags: probability

Suppose an urn has kr balls of k colours and each colour has r balls. From the urn $m\geq k$ balls are drawn with replacement one by one. Let $X_p,p\leq k$ represents the number of drawings required to get balls of p distinct colours.

My solution:
For $X_p=p+m$, where $m$ is a nonengative integer, $P(X_p=p+m)=\frac{\binom{k}{p}\binom{p+m-2}{p-2}}{k^{p+m}}$. My thought was the last draw has to be a $pth$ distinct colour ball, so then the problem becomes to arrange $p+m-1$ balls in $p-1$ cells multiplied by the number of ways to choose those $p$ cells(distinct colour).

So similarly $E[X_p]=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{k}{p}\binom{p+m-2}{p-2}}{k^{p+m}}(p+m)$.

1. Is my probability calculation correct?
2. Is there any further simplification to the mean?

Comment: This is the [coupon collector's problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you!